# Is there a TreeView.getRow() option that does not take into account the current state of each tree item?

Tags: list, javafx, indexing, treeview

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Simply put I would like to be able to get the index of the selected TreeViewItem as if it was a list, irrespective of the state of each TreeViewItem.

`TreeView.getRow(TreeItem)`  gets me an index, but if a leaf is hidden that index changes.

The reason I am looking for this solution is because I am building other lists while I build the TreeView that I would like to reference based on the selection in the TreeView.

Below is a very simple example of what I am trying to acheive:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBoxTreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TreeViewIndexTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        TreeItem root = new TreeItem("root");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList();
        int indexCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            TreeItem parentItem = createBranch("TreeItem " + String.valueOf(indexCounter),root);
            list.add("List Index " + String.valueOf(indexCounter));
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                indexCounter++;
                createBranch("TreeItem " + String.valueOf(indexCounter),parentItem);
                list.add("List Index " + String.valueOf(indexCounter));
            }
            indexCounter++;
        }

        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(root);

        treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((v,oldValue,newValue) -> {
            TreeItem<String> selectedItem = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

            if (selectedItem == null || selectedItem == root)
                return;

            int index = treeView.getRow(selectedItem);

            System.out.println("Index: " + index + "TreeView Item: " + newValue.getValue() + " --- List Value: " + list.get(index));

            //
            //      How can I always return the correct list index based on the selected TreeItem?
            //
            //      The above code does not work
            //

        });

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(treeView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public TreeItem<String> createBranch(String title, TreeItem parent){
        CheckBoxTreeItem newBranch = new CheckBoxTreeItem(title);
        parent.getChildren().add(newBranch);

        return newBranch;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }
}
```

Output if I select the 7th item with the first two leafs open:

`Index: 6TreeView Item: TreeItem 5 --- List Value: List Index 6`

Output if I select the same item with the first leaf closed:

`Index: 3TreeView Item: TreeItem 5 --- List Value: List Index 3`

My guess is that there is another way of going about this, because it must be very common for TreeView selections to access other lists of data.

Any help and examples are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to exactly let us know what you are looking for. From your question there are many pre conditions that we need to look for. So a concrete answer cannot be provided.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post code that creates a `TreeView`. Indicate a sample selection in that `TreeView`. Then post what "index" you expect that selection to provide and what you want to do with that index.

Comment: My first instinct is to say that you're trying to solve the wrong problem. This sort of relationship between data should be handled in the _model_ (or maybe _view model_), not the view. I suspect the `TreeView#getRow(TreeItem)` method is meant mostly for the `MultipleSelectionModel` implementation, as that API works on indices as well as items (a tree structure does not really lend itself to index-based access, though the _visual representation_ is essentially just a list), and to a lesser extent the skin/behavior implementation.

Comment: why _exactly_ do you want to keep a list of indices of the items in a completely flattened treeView (if I understand your requirement correctly)? My gut is it bit in the same state of @Slaw 's instinct :) You would have to keep it in sync on modifications of the tree. Also (didn't try, though) you might traverse the tree structure yourself, starting from the selected item at the time of selection, should be possible with getParent/getPrevious/nextSibling in TreeItem.

Comment: minor nit: the changelistener (mechanism) guarantees the invariant `newValue == selectedItem` - so there's no need for the local field :)

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Your Solution @Slaw provided the results I was looking for.  However I am sure that I am going about it backwards.  I don't have any experience handling data in a model, but I will start learning about it immediately.   Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first instinct is to say that you're trying to solve the wrong problem. This sort of relationship between data should probably be handled in the *model*, or even the *view model* (if you have those), not the *view*. I suspect the `TreeView#getRow(TreeItem)` method is meant mostly to allow creating a `MultipleSelectionModel` implementation, as that API works on indices (as well as items), and to allow `TreeCell`s to report a meaningful index; a tree structure does not really lend itself to index-based access, but the *visual representation* of this sort of tree is essentially just a list.

That said, it's not too difficult to write your own method to ignore the "expanded" state of the items.

```java
// gets the row *index* (zero-based), with root being row 0
public static int getRow(TreeItem<?> item) {
  int index = 0;

  TreeItem<?> parent = item.getParent();
  TreeItem<?> current = item;
  while (parent != null) {
    index++; // account for parent
    // account for any siblings appearing before current item
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildren().indexOf(current); i++) {
      index++; // account for previous sibling itself
      // account for descendants of previous sibling, if any
      index += countDescendants(parent.getChildren().get(i));
    }
    // move up to previous level of tree
    current = parent;
    parent = current.getParent();
  }

  return index;
}

private static int countDescendants(TreeItem<?> item) {
  int count = item.getChildren().size();
  for (TreeItem<?> child : item.getChildren()) {
    count += countDescendants(child);
  }
  return count;
}
```

Note the `TreeView#getRow(TreeItem)` implementation, at least in JavaFX 18.0.1, also calculates the row on-demand (i.e, it's not cached anywhere).